# Why I receive error for a specific method in Play 2?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have this method:

```
def withAuth(f: => User => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
    Authentication.isAuthenticated(AuthenticationToken(AuthenticationService.TokenKey)) match {
      case None => Results.Redirect(routes.AuthenticationService.notLoggedIn)
      case Some(user) => Action(request => f(user)(request))
    }
  }
```

and I use it like:

```
  def list(locationId: Option[Int]) = withAuth { user =>
    implicit request =>
      val entities = Assets.filter(user, locationId)
      Logger.info("Succesfully returned %d assets to user %s".format(entities.length, user))
      Ok(Json.toJson(entities.map(s => Json.toJson(s))))
  }
```

As you notice I want to use it like a method which, if the user is not logged in, `Redirect`s him to login page otherwise returns the user from session. The issue is with that Redirect, on runtime Play is complaining with:

> Cannot use a method returning Object as an Handler

Does anybody has any clue?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the above issues, in the end I did it like:

```
   def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.AuthenticationService.notLoggedIn)

  /**
   * A very important wrapper method which checks if the user is logged-in: if it is, return the User, otherwise
   * redirect the user to a specific page.
   */
  def withAuthentication(f: => Option[User] => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = {
    Security.Authenticated(userId, onUnauthorized) { user =>
      Action(request => f(Users.findById(Integer.valueOf(user)))(request))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the return type of withAuth is not what you think it is. I think you need to wrap your Redirect in an Action.